# Why is SMTP mail activity not working in UiPath

Tags: email, smtp, rpa, uipath

I have a problem with the SMTP mail activity in UiPath. It does not send any mails, neither does it give me any errors. It continues into infinity without exception. Does anybody know why this is happening or is it an error in UiPath's package? I have cross-checked all the errors I could have made and another developer has already looked at it for several hours and still no solution.

In addition, I have searched and there is a solution to getting the error thrown, but it still does not send any mails.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]. As is, your question is impossible to answer. Can you [edit] it and provide some code, as a [mcve]? Include details on your setup; are you running your own smtp server or do you directly connect to e.g., gmail? Note that some servers may bounce an undeliverable email after 2 days or even longer. Also check your spam folder.

Comment: Well could you show your process maybe? The activity works well, maybe your settings are just incorrect. You need to set account password and so on, please double check them as well as the server url.

Comment: @Robert I understand that I did not put in the code or a screenshot but it was intentional since the automation has been in production for several months and there is nothing wrong with the script. I just ran the automation today and mysteriously it worked without changing anything. I think it has something to do with the fact that there was a large update on Windows which was in the way yesterday.